# Wy PHP is better than Javascript in Floating point Arithmetic?

Tags: javascript, php, precision, numeric

PHP

```
<?php echo (-9.341+2.111);
```

Result -7.23

Javascript

```
console.log(2.111-9.341)
```

Result -7.229999999999999

I'm aware of floating Arithmetic, but why vanilla PHP give exact answer and Javascript (tested on Google Chrome console) not?

Comment: You'll find plenty of spots where PHP gives you the repeating numbers too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Both [JavaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) use IEEE 754, echo is probably rounding (note whether a PHP floating point is 32b or 64b is platform dependent)

Comment: `-7.23` appears to have no finite binary representation.

Comment: `echo (-9.341+2.111 == -7.23 ? "true" : "false");` result: false

Comment: @James given that `-7.23` cannot be represented exactly, your example proves nothing.

Comment: It proves that echo is rounding?

Comment: @James I fail to see how it does: you compare one imprecise value with another imprecise value.

Comment: @zerkms we're not trying to prove that -7.23 does or does not have a precise representation in base 2, rather that php doesn't improve over javascript in doing "exact" base-10 math, and that something is affecting the result when it's echoed.

Comment: @James there easily might be a number that does not have exact representation and that is equal to the literal. In that case your example would return true. The result basically depends on how both values were evaluated (and how large the error is) and on nothing more.

Comment: @James `0.1 + 0.1 === 0.2 // true`, even though none of them have exact IEEE754 representation.

Comment: @zerkms My example doesn't have to return false for all values, just 1 case is sufficient to disprove the OP's theory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149179/discussion-between-zerkms-and-james).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is php's `echo` that is rounding:

```
var_dump(sprintf('%.20f', -9.341+2.111)); // string(23) "-7.22999999999999864997"
```

In [php sources](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L547) it looks that `echo` would convert a floating point number to a string using the following conversion:

```
str = zend_strpprintf(0, "%.*G", (int) EG(precision), dval);
```

Which basically means either scientific notation or `%f` (see `precision` configuration directive, 14 by default).

Comment: So it's echo that round by default? But why if I do var_dump(sprintf('%f', -9.341+2.111)) i got "-7.230000". What tell PHP to round at second decimal?

Comment: "i got `-7.230000`." --- and what did you expect to get?

Comment: ok so sprintf round to 6 decimal by default and echo to 15 significative digitist right?

Comment: @FabianoTaioli see the updated answer.